# Can OAuth be done in two legs instead of three?

Tags: api, oauth

I am brand new to OAuth, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.  I'll explain the process as I understand it so far (and ask that you correct me if I'm wrong) and then ask my question.

Step 1:  Client submits a request, via GET, for an Auth Code to the server. Along with that request, client sends a Redirect_URI as a parameter.  The user is asked to authenticate himself against the server, after which he is redirected to the Redirect_URI and is given the Auth Code.

Step 2:  This Auth Code is then used to request an Access Token via a POST.

Step 3: The Access Token can then be used to access the API's.

My question is this:

Is it POSSIBLE to bypass the first step of that process?  Can OAuth be done by jumping right to Step 2?  OR -- what I'm really wondering is -- For my own API's is it possible to secure them via OAuth w/o having to force the first step, because doing so makes it really really hard (if not impossible) to access the API's from an automated service (such as a Window's Service, etc)